# Why is Sencha Cmd not adding most of my ExtJS 4.2 app into app.js

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I wonder if this is because we don't have this app structure:

```
MyApp
    /app
        /controller
        /model
        /store
        /view
```

But instead we have this app structure:

```
MyApp
    /app
        /feature1
            /controller
            /model
            /store
            /view
        /feature2
            /controller
            /model
            /store
            /view
```

Here is a sample define:

```
Ext.define('base.model.Job', {
```

Here is from app.js

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'AMC',
    appFolder: 'app',


    requires: [
        'base.model.Job',
```

---

I'm looking into using Sencha Cmd 4.0.2.67. I generated a skeleton app with generate, created a workspace and a package, and sencha app build runs fine, no errors or warnings.

But when I look in the /workspace/build/production/AMC/ folder, minified app.js has only 19 Ext.define, but my app has at least 250 Ext.define for all my classes.

I thought when I define app.js in my dev environment, dependencies would be resolved, and all mode code would be minified and put in app.js in production.

Here is an example of my app.js in my dev enviroment:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled : true
});


Ext.application({
    name: 'AMC',
    appFolder: 'app',


    requires: [
        'atlas.model.Pool',
        'atlas.model.Volume',
        'base.model.Job',
        'atlas.model.Performance',
        'atlas.utilities.CommonUtil',
        'atlas.utilities.CommonVTypes'
    ],


    views: [
        'atlas.view.login.Login'
    ],


    controllers: [
        'atlas.wizard.impl.hanode.controller.WizardHaNodeController',
        'atlas.wizard.impl.agg.controller.WizardAggController',
        'atlas.wizard.impl.disk.controller.WizardDiskController',
        'atlas.wizard.impl.mem.controller.WizardMemController',
        'atlas.wizard.impl.ads.controller.WizardAdsController',


        'atlas.wizard.base.controller.WizardReviewController',
        'atlas.wizard.base.controller.WizardWindowController',
        'atlas.wizard.base.controller.WizardPanelController',
        'atlas.wizard.base.controller.WizardFormTypeTierController',
        'atlas.wizard.base.controller.WizardFormTypeOptimizeController',
        'atlas.wizard.base.controller.WizardFormTypeInMemoryController',
        'atlas.wizard.base.controller.WizardFormTypeMemoryPureController',
        'atlas.wizard.base.controller.WizardLookupDataStoreController',
        'atlas.wizard.base.controller.WizardLookupImportsController',
        'atlas.wizard.base.controller.WizardLookupHostDatastoreController',


        'atlas.controller.ha.HaNodeController',
        'atlas.controller.portlet.GraphiteController',
        'atlas.controller.setting.VcenterController',
        'atlas.controller.setting.SettingController',
        'atlas.controller.PerspectiveController',
        'atlas.controller.cluster.AssignVolumeToClusterController',
        'atlas.controller.cluster.AssignPoolToClusterController',
        'atlas.controller.login.LoginController',
        'atlas.controller.ha.DeleteHAConfigController',
        'atlas.controller.ha.CreateHAConfigController',
        'atlas.controller.pool.AddAggregatorToPoolController',
        'base.controller.HeaderLinkController',
        'atlas.wizard.base.controller.WizardOptionsController',
        'base.controller.task.TaskListController',
        'base.controller.TabPanelController',
        'atlas.controller.cloud.CloudGettingStartedController',
        'atlas.controller.cloud.CloudOverviewController',
        'atlas.controller.aggregator.AggregatorHostListController'
    ],


    models: [
        'atlas.model.Pool',
        'atlas.model.Volume',
        'base.model.Job',
        'atlas.model.Performance',
        'base.model.Task'
    ],


    stores: [
        'atlas.wizard.base.store.WizardHaConfigStore',
        'atlas.store.PerformancePoolTypeStore',
        'atlas.store.PerformanceVolumeTypeStore',
        'atlas.store.PerformanceChartTypeStore',
        'atlas.store.TimeRangeStore'
    ],


    init: function()
    {
        var me = this;
        me.setRestWebServiceUrl();


        delete Ext.tip.Tip.prototype.minWidth;


        // This statement is disabling browser default context menu when right-clicking in ExtJS.
        Ext.getBody().on("contextmenu", Ext.emptyFn, null, {preventDefault: true});
    },


    launch: function()
    {
        //Ext.create('atlas.view.login.LoginForm');
        Ext.create('atlas.view.login.Login');
        //Ext.create('atlas.view.Viewport');
    },


    onAddController : function(index, controller, key)
    {
        controller.init(this);
    },


    getPerspective: function()
    {
        return this.perspective;
    },


    getPerspectiveId: function()
    {
        return this.perspectiveId;
    },


    getPerspectiveController : function()
    {
        return this.getController('atlas.controller.PerspectiveController');
    }
});
```

Comment: Can anyone comment on this?

Comment: Well, I went through the guide here, and after building, then changing the name of the controller, then building again, the compressed build folder app.js did not change. Now I'm totally confused about using Sencha Cmd.

Comment: I see a lot of lines like this:

accumulating symbols for file D:\atlantis\amc\gui\src\main\webappnew\workspace\extApps\usx\app\base\view\TreePanel.js

and this:

[DBG] Detected active instantiation reference to base.view.TreePanel in file D:\atlantis\amc\gui\src\main\webappnew\workspace\extApps\usx\app\base\view\TreePanel.js
[DBG] Adding dynamic requirement on base.view.TreePanel to TreePanel.js as a GenericAutoDependency

and this:

[DBG] Enabling transitive dependencies for D:\atlantis\amc\gui\src\main\webappnew\workspace\extApps\usx\app\base\view\TreePanel.js

Comment: I would recommend asking this question in the Cmd forum: http://www.sencha.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?8-Sencha-Cmd